# iOS - How to check if UIDocument is open elsewhere on iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud, uidocument

Is there a way to check if a UIDocument (that is being synced with iCloud) has been opened elsewhere using iCloud--other than waiting for a conflict to happen?